# Can not pass the 2FA of OCI

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have problems to login my OCI console. I setup 2FA by Oracle Authenticator App already. Unfortunately I changed my phone, and did not transfer data to new one, that was a stupid mistake. Now I can not pass the 2FA and of course I don't have the Bypass-Code which is the second method that OCI provide.
My question is how can I get my account back. Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem. How do you fix it?

Comment: no, I send the email to OCI for two months, it looks like their office is on the Mars... never replied.